# How can I Authenticate Users on Firebase with an OAuth Implicit Grant Access Token Generated by a Wordpress Plugin?

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, jwt, google-cloud-functions

I have an Angular App which connects to my Wordpress site for authentication. I use the free wordpress plugin from https://wordpress.org/plugins/oauth2-provider/ to validate if a user is signed in to the Wordpress site and return data about the logged in user (Implicit grant type). I then use this information on the Angular app.

This works fine, but now I also want to connect the Angular app to a Firebase project and make use of its Cloud Firestore DB as well as its Cloud Storage features. Naturally, I'll need to authenticate on Firebase as well, right? I checked their Documentation and see that they do allow authentication with custom tokens but only accept JWTs signed using their SDK.

Since I have no idea about Wordpress development and the Wordpress plugin doesn't seem to have the feature to generate JWTs signed with Firebase SDK, I am thinking of using a Firebase or GCP Cloud Function to act as an intermediary to convert the Access Token generated by the Wordpress plugin to a JWT that can help me authenticate users on Firebase.

This is the rough outline of what I've already built:

1. User reaches Angular app's url.
2. App checks for access token fragment in url. If not present, the app automatically redirects the user to Wordpress Site's oauth endpoint url created by plugin.
3. Wordpress oAuth plugin checks if user is logged in to the Wordpress site.
4. If the user is logged in, it redirects them back to the Angular App with access token as a URL fragment. Else it redirects them to the Login page.
5. Angular app again checks url, finds access token and now loads the proper app view with data.

The following are things that I plan to build next:
6) After the above step, the Angular app makes a POST request to a Firebase/GCP cloud function with the access token and details of authenticated user - email, username and id.
7) The cloud function uses Firebase SDK and service account credentials to generate a JWT with the User's data and sends it back to the Angular App as response.
8) The Angular App can use this JWT to authenticate the same user with Firebase and start using the Firebase features such as Firestore and Storage.

My question is if this approach is correct? I am not sure if simply making a POST request to a cloud function and getting back a JWT is the secure and the correct way to go about creating a JWT for Firebase authentication.

I can use Firebase's Anonymous sign in but then I would not be able to restrict a user to be able to only access content on the Firestore DB that they created.

My concern with steps 6 to 8 above is that there is no validation possible on the cloud function when generating the JWT. It is simply -> send details to this endpoint, get a jwt as response. If someone manages to find out the endpoint, they could easily send any random data to the endpoint, get a JWT as response, sign in to Firebase and gain access to the DB and storage.

Is there any way I can improve this approach (like, how can I validate the JWT token request on the Cloud function) or is there any alternate approach to this that I'm not seeing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: In step 6), are you attempting to [verify the ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) of the user account? This should be enough to thwart access to the endpoint directly.

Comment: @KevinH No, that token is the implicit access token returned by the oAuth system. Right now, I'm doing another validation at the server in order to verify if the token supplied to the endpoint is valid. This seems okay for now.However, the endpoint is still open to the public. Not sure if this is a problem.

Comment: Apologies for the misunderstanding, as I am not well versed in Firebase authentication, I have attempted a best effort solution to the issue you are facing. In this case, in order to gain a better opinion of your authentication setup, I would recommend inquiring with [Firebase support directly](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact).